# Calculate Download Speed Like ookla

Tags: javascript, download-speed

Can anyone please let me know how I can properly calculate the download speed like Ookla speed tester.

I have tried to calculate it with the following approach but still not getting the correct result.

I am downloading a file from `CDN` and calculate the time it takes to download the complete file.  Then divide it.
for e.g.:

1. open a connection with `URL`
2. var starting time in milliseconds.
3. download the file
4. `var endTime` in milliseconds
5. `Speed = (downloadSize in bits) / ((endTime-Startime)/1000)`

Comment: What result did you expect to get?

Comment: What result did you get and how is it different with your expected result?

Comment: when i run the test from ookla i get aroung 10 - 15 Mbps downloading speed. while when i run my code i get 1 - 3  Mbps speed .

Comment: @Tin Kills seems like there is a ~8 ratio there, are you sure you're not missing a bytes to bits conversion in your calculations ?

Comment: @BJRINT no the conversion is correct .  is there any better way to do this. i am currently doing this with javascript . or do i need to condiser any other factors in calcutation

Comment: Whilst I am not the man to help you with this problem **you should post your code**

Comment: @Tin Kills Assuming you have some control over the backend you could handle this with a [stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) and the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) by breaking the downloaded data into small chunks and getting the instant rate of bytes/ms (which is what i assume Ookla does). This will be pretty accurate, but if it is really worth the effort for your use case that I cannot answer ...